# Access dimensions in color histogram openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, multidimensional-array, histogram, channel

I'm a novice in openCV and here goes my first doubt about matrix dimension subjects.

I am computing the Histogram of a colored image by means of the function *cv::calcHist(..)*.

The resulting matrix is, as I expected, a 3D matrix. I guess the third dimension means the color for each RGB color channel but I don't know how to access them. After computing it, I have a matrix of 3 dimensions and 1 channel, and I'd like to be able to access each single dimension.

I think split function can't help here since it only splits a matrix into its channels.

Debugging I obtain the following relevant info from the 3Dhistrogram matrix:

*Dimensions: 3,
Rows: -1,
Columns: -1,
Size: 256*

I know I can obtain the individual color histogram by splitting first the image into the 3 channels and computing the 1D histogram of each one afterwards but I'm curious about knowing how work the dimensions in openCV.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you seen this [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_calculation/histogram_calculation.html)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but there they're splitting the image before and computing the individual histograms as I mention.
I'm asking about handling the 3 dimensions matrix resulted from computing the histogram directly form the colored image:
cv::calcHist(&image,1,channels,cv::Mat(), hist,3,histSize,ranges);

It's more a question about how to handle these dimensions (no channels) than about the histogram.

Answer (score 0):

Here is from Opencv's reference on MatND class:

```
   // return pointer to the element (versions for 1D, 2D, 3D and generic nD cases)
    uchar* ptr(int i0);
    const uchar* ptr(int i0) const;
    uchar* ptr(int i0, int i1);
    const uchar* ptr(int i0, int i1) const;
    uchar* ptr(int i0, int i1, int i2);
    const uchar* ptr(int i0, int i1, int i2) const;
    uchar* ptr(const int* idx);
    const uchar* ptr(const int* idx) const;

    // convenient template methods for element access.
    // note that _Tp must match the actual matrix type -
    // the functions do not do any on-fly type conversion
    template<typename _Tp> _Tp& at(int i0);
    template<typename _Tp> const _Tp& at(int i0) const;
    template<typename _Tp> _Tp& at(int i0, int i1);
    template<typename _Tp> const _Tp& at(int i0, int i1) const;
    template<typename _Tp> _Tp& at(int i0, int i1, int i2);
    template<typename _Tp> const _Tp& at(int i0, int i1, int i2) const;
    template<typename _Tp> _Tp& at(const int* idx);
    template<typename _Tp> const _Tp& at(const int* idx) const;
```

So, you can use array of 3 elements as an argument of .at method to set required element position.